# I vertically concatenate two files in R but when I did that, I have 3:1 variables instead of 1:1

Tags: r, merge, rbind

I have merged two files using rbind and merge in R but when I did that, one of the variable was replicated three times instead of one time.I do not know where I did wrong. The rbind works great but I think the merge did not work in vertically concatenate the files.

I did rbind first and then use merge two files and check everything but I do not know where it went wrong.#

### Input Data

```
 d<-
 structure(list(taxa = c("CARYA", "CATE9", "FRAXINUS", "FRPE", "Juniperus", "JUVI", "QUERCUS", "QUERCUS", "QUERCUS", "QUERCUS", "QUERCUS", "QUERCUS", "QUERCUS", "QUERCUS", "QUERCUS", "QUMA3", "QUSH", "QUST", "SIDER", "SILAR20"), even.image = c(12L, 12L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 26L, 2L, 2L), odd.image = c(6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 25L, 7L, 10L, 25L, 7L, 10L, 25L, 7L, 10L, 7L, 25L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("taxa", "even.image", "odd.image"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

### Output format

The output I am looking is the following:

```
Species     Even.image   Odd.Image
QUSH         26           25
QUST         9             7
QUMA3        7            10
QUERCUS      26           25
QUERCUS      9            7
QUERCUS      7           10
```

I do not what I am missing when merging EI and OI.EI have Species and even.image and OI have species and odd.image.

```
Image<- merge(EI,OI)
```

Comment: It's very hard to tell from what you've written how to help. The best I can say is that `rbind` and `merge` do very different things and are not interchangeable. `merge` is for doing joins, like you would in SQL. `rbind` is for "stacking" data frames on top of each other into a single data frame (assuming similar structures), (like a UNION in SQL).

Comment: How do I input dataset here so that reader can have idea of what I am talking about

Comment: Create two small data sets to exhibit the problematic behavior (just a handful of rows) and then edit them into your question, either as you have above, or by calling `dput()` on them in R and then copy & pasting the results into your question.

Comment: structure(list(taxa = c("CARYA", "CATE9", "FRAXINUS", "FRPE", "Juniperus", 
"JUVI", "QUERCUS", "QUERCUS", "QUERCUS", "QUERCUS", "QUERCUS", 
"QUERCUS", "QUERCUS", "QUERCUS", "QUERCUS", "QUMA3", "QUSH", 
"QUST", "SIDER", "SILAR20"), even.image = c(12L, 12L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 26L, 2L, 
2L), odd.image = c(6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 25L, 7L, 10L, 
25L, 7L, 10L, 25L, 7L, 10L, 7L, 25L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("Image", 
"taxa", "even.image", "odd.image"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: QUERCUS is genus while QUMA3, QUSH and QUST are species. So there should be 3 species and 3 genus out of the table, not 9 genus.

Comment: @joran Can you see the data now? I think the issue is with merging. I cannot use cbind as the two files have different size and I used unique to get the unique variables but still there are some issues. Do you know how to get the output that I have in my first post?

Comment: Put the data in your question not in comments. You marked the answer below as "accepted". That signals to everyone looking at this question that that answer solved your problem and that no one should bother trying to help anymore.

Comment: I did that. Thank you @Joran.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have duplicate values in your right side.  Make sure you're joining distinct values.

Comment: No I do not have duplicate values. When I merge it, it is acting funny.